# PySpark Kernel in GCP - unicode strings

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a column containing strings. When I call the function:

```
df = spark.read.csv(path, header=True).show()
```

I get the correct "view", however when I print

```
print("dataframe as a RDD object (list of Row objects):\n\t", df.collect())
```

The result is strings with unicode symbol like `u'mystring'`

How can I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.x you have `str` and `unicode`. Objects surround by `u'mytext'` are Unicode.

To convert from unicode to str:

```
mystr = unistr.encode('utf-8')
```

To convert str to unicode:

```
unistr = mystr.decode('utf-8')
```

In Python 2.x, I usually leave strings as Unicode until I need to write them to a file, etc. In Python 3.x, all strings are Unicode.

The following document will help understand:

[Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)